# match and subset

Tags: r

I have a situation like this:
data.frame1 (240 columns and variable number of rows):

> ```
>  COL1  COL2  COL3
>   a      e    h
>   b      f    i
>   c      g    l
>   d
> ```

and data.frame2

> ```
>  Gene  VAL  
>   a    3   
>   b    7   
>   c    0.5   
>   d    3.7
>   e    9.08
>   f    1.3
>  ...   ...
> ```

I would like to match and subset each COL of the first data.frame with the data.frame2 (so with the first column of the second data.frame) recursively in order to have the following output:

out:
data.frame3

> ```
>    COL1   VAL      COL2   VAL
>      a     3        e    9.08
>      b     7        f    1.3
>     ...   ...      ....  ....
> ```

any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the function `lapply`:

```
data.frame1 <- data.frame(COL1 = letters[1:3], COL2 = c(NA, letters[5], NA))
data.frame2 <- data.frame(Gene = letters[1:6], VAL = rnorm(6))

do.call("cbind",
  lapply(data.frame1,
    function(x) { VAL <- rep(NA, ncol(data.frame1));
      VAL[!is.na(x)] <- data.frame2$VAL[data.frame2$Gene %in% na.omit(x)];
      return(data.frame(x, VAL)) }))

#  COL1.x   COL1.VAL COL2.x  COL2.VAL
#1      a  0.1601884   <NA>        NA
#2      b -0.2035409      e -1.535597
#3      c -0.6661004   <NA>        NA
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but with a problem. The data.frame1 has columns with an equal number of rows in your case. In my case the first data.frame has different number of rows per column...I know that R has problems reading input data with different row length..

Comment: The lengths of the rows of a data frame are always identical. Please provide some example data. What is the result of `str(data.frame1)`?

Comment: Looks like matrix. However, the row lengths should be identical. What are the values where the rows are "incomplete"?

Comment: sorry....I posted the wrong answer. the real str(data.frame1) result is:data.frame': 366 obs. of  17 variables:

Comment: OK, but what makes some rows "imcomplete"? Do they contain `NA`?

Comment: I think you won't be able to escape the `merge`. Possibly in combination with `mapply`.

Comment: Yes! Since rows are of different length, NA are introduced. After running your code the error is:Error in data.frame(x, data.frame2$SD[data.frame2$Gene_name %in% x]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 366, 105